# LocalStorage in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Are there different LocalStorage stores for normal Browser and Selenium Browser? When i create an item on selenium chrome, after i close the browser the item is gone. Is this intended? Also i can't read the localStorage from the normal Browser

Edit: To be more specific:

If i enter in the console on my Selenium chrome browser

`localStorage.setItem("test", "This is a test value"); 
localStorage.getItem("test");` => prints "This is a test value" as intended

But if i close the Selenium chrome and reopen it and try to get the same value from the same page `localStorage.getItem("test");`=> null

As i have read from different posts, they can normally work with localStorage in Selenium.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Could you expand a little more on what you mean when you say you can't read the local storage from the normal browser. I.e. Do you mean you can't read it when it's adding items to the local storage on the Selenium Browser? I'm not sure of the solution myself, but I'm keen to discover if there is one, so upvote from me!

Answer (score 4):

**Javascript / Node**

I had the same problem for the reasons explained by previous answers ; local storage is per profile and Selenium opens with a new profile and a new empty local storage each time.

To keep the local storage across selenium page launches, use the same profile:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

const chromeProfilePath = 'C:\\Users\\Bob\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data';

let options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments(`--user-data-dir=${chromeProfilePath}`); 
let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(options)
    .build();
```

You can get the profile path by typing chrome://version in the browser.

**IMPORTANT**: remove the "default" from the end of that path as chrome adds it back on again.

Also, changes to Chrome/ChromeDriver post v74 require associated changes in selenium-webdriver for options to work - make sure you have the appropriate version of selenium-webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Thought `localStorage` **is** persistent across browser's re-openings - as opposed to `sesionStorage` which does not survive even a tab close, that persistence is per browser profile.

Whenever Chrome and Firefox browser sessions get created, by default they start off with a new (almost blank) profile - and now you can see why your `localStorage` data got wiped.

In your example, when you created the entries in the first session they were in fact stored; but once you started the new session, it was in a different profile - and its `localStorage` was empty.

This default behavior (of starting with a new profile) does make sense - if the browser's `localStorage` was shared/survived between browsers re-openings, then a previous session's data would pollute the environment for consecutive tests, leading to unexpected results. Consider the case where a session stores in `localStorage` a setting "the user wants to hide this information from the UI", and a follow-up suite's purpose is to verify that same information - its environment is changed from the norm ("polluted"), and leads to unexpected state.

The default behavior can be overridden - the browsers can be started with specific profiles, thus giving the persistence if needed.

I said Chrome and Firefox start with a new profile, yet IE is started with a default one, which probably will persist `localStorage` - but don't quote me on this :)

---

Finally, to address a misconception - `localStorage` is saved on the user's disk drive (thus it's persisted), **not** in the browser's memory; `sessionStorage` is purely in-memory (another way to guarantee it won't survive browser re-opening).

Answer (score -1):

The question is "where is the data being stored"? The answer is that it is stored in the browser, not in Selenium. Therefore, when the last browser tab or window is closed, the data is lost forever.

If you open a browser and use localStorage.setItem, the data will be stored in the browser memory. And then you open another tab or window from that session and close only the first tab/window, then the browser still retains the data. But as soon as you close the last tab/window, the data will be lost.

The conclusion is that if you want to use data across browser windows, you must do so before closing the last window or tab.

Comment: But when i save an item in my firefox and reopen it, i can still get that item after. It works in normal Browsers, but why not in Selenium controlled ones?